# How to create attribute in flexcontainer in oneM2M?

Tags: onem2m

I am trying to create attribute in flexcontainer in oneM2M, i have created container and contentinstance in oneM2M. Now I need to use flexcontainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess from your question that you try to directly create a <flexContainer> resource. That is not possible. The <flexContainer> can be viewed as an "abstract base class" that needs to be further specified. In oneM2M these derived resource types are called *specialisations*. A *specialisation* takes all the resource specific attributes from the <flexContainer> and adds the custom attributes that actually represent the functional part. This *specialisation* can now be created, retrieved etc like any other resource.

Take, for example, the *clock* specialisation that is defined in oneM2M's TS-0023 document. It adds three new custom attributes, namely *currentTime*, *currentDate*, and *currentTimeZone* in order to represent a clock functionality.

Please note that the CSE implementation you are using needs to support the <flexContainer> resource type in general, and the specific specialisations you want to use. If you want to create your own specialisations then the CSE must support user-defined specialisations and their validations as well.

The oneM2M specifications are available here: https://www.onem2m.org/technical/published-specifications

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the resource link.

Comment: could you please help me with this error?

Comment: {"m2m:dbg": "Release Version Indicator is missing in request, falling back to RVI='1'. But Release Version '1' is not supported. Use RVI with one of ['2a', '3', '4']."}

Comment: I assume that you are using http to access the CSE. In this case you need to add a header "X-M2M-RVI:3" to your request. This indicates the specification version number used. Instead of 3 you can use any of the indicated strings from the debug message. Please Check also the basic introduction at https://www.onem2m.org/using-onem2m/developers/api#n2c